# Firebird remote connection failure

Tags: c++, sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a C++ application that used to read the data from the Firebird SQL server.

when I changed port from 3050 to 3053 it shows error like

```
DB Error : 0 : Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.47".
Failed to establish a connection.
unknown Win32 error 10060
Invalid connection string attribute
```

conf file is changed like

```
# Type: string, integer
#
RemoteServiceName = gds_db
RemoteServicePort = 3053
```

Fb connection string is

```
Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;DBNAME=192.168.1.47:CWNPFB;PORT=3053;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=********
```

Is there any modification is required to solve this? Application can read the data if the port is 3050.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your connection string:

You need to

1. Remove `PORT=3053` from the connection string (this causes the *"Invalid connection string attribute"* message)
2. Modify `DBNAME=192.168.1.47:CWNPFB` to `DBNAME=192.168.1.47/3053:CWNPFB` (to specify the right port)

You might also want to comment out (or remove) the line `RemoteServiceName = gds_db`, because you are now instructing Firebird to listen on `gds_db` (== port 3050), and not on port 3053. I believe it usually listens on the last one configured in the config file, but I'm not sure that is always the case.

Comment: `Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;DBNAME=192.168.1.47/5645:CWNPFB;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=*******`


**DB Error : 0 : Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.47".
Failed to establish a connection.
unknown Win32 error 10060**

@mark

Comment: @MarshalSebastian Port 5645 != 3053, what port is your Firebird server really listening on?

Comment: now the port is changed to 5645 and set the query string as like your suggestion but the issue is not solved.

Comment: @MarshalSebastian Error 10060 is a connection time out, which might also suggest that a firewall is interfering. You say that application works when Firebird is running on port 3050: you can check that my solution should work by using `DBNAME=192.168.1.47/3050:CWNPFB`. If changing the Firebird port and entering that port in the connection string then doesn't work, the problem is not with the connection string, but with something (firewall, other service running on that port?) blocking the port.

Comment: now it is working. thanks for your valuable help. issue is with the connection string. now i corrected as like your suggestion
`DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=*******;DBNAME=marshal/5645:CWNPFB`

now i can access my db

Answer (score 0):

Is your firewall configuration correct for port 3053? Another service may runs on this special port.

**You could do the following steps.**

1. Try to run the application on the database server, please change the IP to 127.0.0.1 or localhost.
2. If step (1) works: check out the firewall
3. If step (1) doesn't work: maybe try another port, check whether Firebird is running

Comment: TCP port 3053 is allowed in the firewall and firebird service is running. i can access the server in localhost app.